# How do I find the roll, pitch, and yaw angles of a plane (/or a plane that coincides with 3 points in space ) in 3D?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, 3d, robotics

Imagine that we have 3 points $P_1,P_2$ and $P_3$. $P_1,P_2,P_3$ creates a plane in 3D space. Let's say the plane equation is $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$. How can I find the roll, pitch, yaw angles of this plane?
$R(r,p,y)=R_z(y)R_y(p)R_x(r)$  order  or any other order. Roll angle for the rotation angle around the $x$ axis. Pitch angle for the rotation angle around the $y$ axis. Yaw angle for the rotation angle around the $z$ axis.

Note: I tried to find the normal vector (normal vector $n=Ux+Vy+Wz$) of the plane. Is this useful to use this normal vector? For example; the $x$ axis vector is $v_x=[1,0,0]$. Does it help to find the dot product of normal vector and $x$ axis vector? Therefore, I can find the arccos of this dot product vector, and find angle between those two vectors.  But this is not one of the roll,pitch,yaw angles. However, I wanted to ask if it helps to find and use the normal vector of the plane.

Comment: I think the first step would be to find the rotation matrix. From that it's pretty easy to interpret the Euler angles.

Comment: Dear @MattiP. , rotation matrix is defined using the roll,pitch,yaw angles. But we don't know yet those angles. Is there another way to find the corresponding rotation matrix ?

Comment: Start with the 2d case.  You have 2 points P1 and P2 forming a line.  How do you determine the angle that line forms with your x axis?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please use [MathJax](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: The normal vector will be perpendicular to $P_2-P_1, P_3-P_1$.

Comment: Dear @epte , for 2D case; I would determine the line equation which coincide with two points (P1 and P2). Then I would determine the slope (tangent) from the line equation of P1-P2. Or directly I can find the tangent using the two points P1 and P2. After that, I would find the angle forming with x axis, using the arctangent of that found tangent.

Comment: It is possible to do it that way.  Consider where your plane crosses your axes, by setting a coordinate in your plane equation to 0.  That should give you three line equations, one for each coordinate you set to zero.  Solve for the angle as above.

Comment: Dear @epte , thank you for your answer. But those angles aren't what I mean.  Maybe my question wasn't clear, so I edited now. I can find the angles as you described. For example the angle between the x axis and vector which lies on the plane. However, what I mean to ask is different: I wanted to find the rotation angle "around the x axis". Similar to this graph: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138941/rotation-with-roll-pitch-and-yaw-in-different-coordinate-system

Comment: How are they different?  Setting the x coord of your plane to 0 will find the line of intersection in the y-z plane, and that line will be rotated around the x-axis in order to acheive that angle.  That finds the pitch angle.

Comment: Are you asking about roll, pitch, yaw with respect to the standard orientation?

Comment: I tried to make my question more simple. And I asked my question in another new post. Since it seems to be  a little bit different question, I posted it in a separated post. It is in this link here: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992619/how-to-find-rotation-matrix-for-a-given-position) . Thanks to everyone who is trying to help me with my question.